# write the contents of application page to a file in WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to write the entire contents of my application page (eg Mainpage.xml) to a file (in Isolated Storage ) How do I do it in WP7 ? are there any methods available to parse the page contents and write it to file in windows phone 7 ?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I want to extract test results from Microsoft.Silverlight.Testing framework result page. So that I can write them to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built in way to do this.

However there are a couple of approaches you could try:

If the structure is static you could try and extract the resource containing this from the DLL. For future re-use it would be easier to load the page from the DLL again though.

If you're generating a page (or part of a page) at runtime (based on user input/preferences) and you want to be able to save/reload this then just save enough information to be able to recreate it. It's unlikely that XAML would be the best format for this though.
You could create this as you build the UI. Alternatively you could walk the visual tree to get details of all that is rendered. I'd recommend recording as you go so you can more easily keep track of non-default values in the rendered objects.